# Google Tag Manager - Data Layers

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I was looking into implementing Google Tag Manager: Data Layers so better track the behaviour of my users and I was wondering if the following was possible:

Pushing data to multiple Google Tag Managers

- Either through custom javascript or
- Just placing two Google Tag Managers and letting the DataLayer push to both of them?

Basically, we have two parties who want to data, however, one party will have access to more information while the other will only need some of the datalayer push

For example:

1. Party 1: DataLayer push - "Name", "product", "no of product sold"
2. Party 2: DataLayer push - includes all of the above plus "cost","margin" etc

Thanks in advance,
Lee.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, even in multi-GTM situation, you use one DL.

Typically, you never give third party data consumers access to your GTM because that gives them the power to execute arbitrary JS on all your pages and that is a serious security concern. If it's necessary, consider not giving them publish access to veto their tracking implementation.

One GTM instance can handle numerous stakeholders and send different pieces of data to different endpoints.